# Trying to create a reactive graph that will take in multiple different inputs in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dplyr, plotly

I have added multiple select inputs to my shiny app in the sidebar and in the main body and want to create a graph that will change when any of those inputs have been selected or changed but I keep getting the error Warning: Error in : Result must have length 56127, not 0.

UI:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Human Trafficking"),

    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            selectInput("Source", "Choose a Data Source: ", choices = " ", selected = NULL,
                        multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL),
            dateInput("startdate", "Start Date:", value = "2009-01-01", format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                      min = "2009-01-01", max = "2019-08-26"),

            dateInput("enddate", "End Date:", value = "2019-08-27", format = "dd-mm-yyyy",
                      min = "2009-01-02", max = "2019-08-27"),
            selectInput("Nationality", "Select a nation: ", choices = " "),
            actionButton("button", "Apply")
        )
    ),

    dashboardBody(

        fluidRow(
            box(width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE,
                selectInput("traffickingType", "Choose a trafficking type: ", choices = " ", selected = NULL,
                            multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
            ),
            box(width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE,
                selectInput("traffickingSubType", "Choose a trafficking sub type: ", choices = " ", selected = NULL,
                            multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
            ),
            box(width = 4, solidHeader = TRUE,
                selectInput("gender", "Choose a gender: ", choices = " ", selected = NULL,
                            multiple = TRUE, selectize = TRUE, width = NULL, size = NULL)
            )
        ),
        fluidRow(
            box(width = 12,
                plotlyOutput('coolplot')
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  genderVic = sort(unique(ngo$Victim.Gender))
  updateSelectInput(session, "gender", choices = genderVic)

  traffickingSub = sort(unique(ngo$Trafficking.Sub.Type))
  updateSelectInput(session, "traffickingSubType", choices = traffickingSub)

  trafficking = sort(unique(ngo$Trafficking.Type))
  updateSelectInput(session, "traffickingType", choices = trafficking)

  traffickerNationalities = sort(unique(ngo$Trafficker.Nationality))
  updateSelectInput(session, "TraffickerNation", choices = traffickerNationalities)

  dataSource = sort(unique(ngo$Data.Provided.By))
  updateSelectInput(session, "Source", choices = dataSource)

  nationalities = sort(unique(ngo$Victim.Nationality))
  updateSelectInput(session, "Nationality", choices = nationalities)

  output$coolplot <- renderPlotly({
    ngo <-
      ngo %>%
      filter(Victim.Nationality == input$Nationality,
             Victim.Gender == input$gender,
             Trafficking.Type == input$traffickingType
      )

    p = ggplot(ngo, aes(x = Victim.Age, fill = Trafficking.Type)) + 
      geom_bar(position = "stack")
    ggplotly(p) %>%
      layout(showlegend = FALSE)
  })
}
```

So currently only have it calling three of the inputs to test it but still getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work after the error is displayed once you select a gender and trafficking type in your example. The reason for the error is that renderPlotly is expecting values for `input$traffickingType` and `input$gender` but these start out as `NULL`.

Add a `req` for each of those `selectInput`s:

```
    output$coolplot <- renderPlotly({
        ngo <-
            ngo %>%
            filter(Victim.Nationality == input$Nationality,
                   Victim.Gender == req(input$gender),
                   Trafficking.Type == req(input$traffickingType)
            )

        p = ggplot(ngo, aes(x = Victim.Age, fill = Trafficking.Type)) + 
            geom_bar(position = "stack")
        ggplotly(p) %>%
            layout(showlegend = FALSE)
    })
```